# Cisco Catalyst 3750 switch port for VMWare ESX

Tags: cisco-ios, cisco-commands

We have a VMWare ESXi host with a single network port. It's connected to a Cisco Catalyst 3750 switch port and the configuration of thew switch port is as follows:

```
interface FastEthernet 1/0/2
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
end
```

We need to run a guest on a separate vlan (vlan 11 and 12) and so we change the switch configuration as follows:

```
interface FastEthernet 1/0/2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q 
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport trunk native vlan 10
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 10,11,12
end
```

When this is done we lose access to the host. What is wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESXi does not support DTP dynamic trunking protocol and portfast trunk should be enabled.

```
switchport nonegotiate !Skip DTP negotiation
spanning-tree portfast trunk !Fast forward STP state
```

In addition, do not use the native (untagged) vlan on any portgroups.  Use the native vlan for the management or service-console VMKernel networks which also allow kickstarting for installs over DHCP or BOOTP before tagging can be used.